# Modify TM_FILENAME_BASE in VSCode Snippets

Tags: python, code-snippets

I want to modify the $TM_FILENAME_BASE to generate a code snippet. As an example, I have a file that is called new_animals.py

This is my actual snippet

```
{
    "Create Python": {
        "prefix": "py_snippet",
        "body": [
            "class $TM_FILENAME_BASE():",
            "    _inherit = '$TM_FILENAME_BASE'",
            "",
            "$0"
        ],
        "description": "Create Python"
    }
}
```

$TM_FILENAME_BASE in the snippet, generates `new_animals`

And i want 2 conversions

- The first one I want to generate is `new.animals` (Replace the _ with .)
- The second one is `NewAnimals` (Capitalize and replace _ with empty)

Could you help me to accomplish this please? Thank you! :)

My snippet is generating this actually

```
class product_template():
    _inherit = 'product_template'
```

And i want to generate this

```
class ProductTemplate():
    _inherit = 'product.template'
```